# jq filter remove or replace tab from inside @tsv

Tags: json, jq

Input json:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1e9b2215-9efd-67cc-9113-2b21c74f09d3",
    "login": "u0154",
    "name": "Roman ABC",
    "role": "User",
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": "1e99833f-9876-65d0-9d24-237228b9d9e0",
        "name": "AGE"
      }
    ],
    "disabled": false,
    "lLoginTime": 1567158950468,
    "lLoginFrom": "192.168.100.11"
  },
  {
    "id": "1e9b2215-9c2b-64f4-a0f1-47abdab7ae5f",
    "login": "u0155",
    "name": "Tomas CDE",
    "role": "User",
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": "1e8dc82a-596f-623c-8bc5-100000000000",
        "name": "ZZZ"
      },
      {
        "id": "1e99234f-9876-65d0-9d24-534528b9d9e0",
        "name": "NTE"
      }
    ],
    "disabled": false,
    "lLoginTime": 1566302653093,
    "lLoginFrom": "192.168.100.16"
  }
]
```

I need to print tab separated .id, .login and all user groups separated by | (pipe) or comma

What I have now:

```
$ jq -r '.[]|[.id, .login, ([.groups[].name]|@tsv)]|@tsv' test.json
1e9b2215-9efd-67cc-9113-2b21c74f09d3    u0154   AGE
1e9b2215-9c2b-64f4-a0f1-47abdab7ae5f    u0155   ZZZ\tNTE
```

I need to modify filter so groups which are on the last column are separated with space or `|` instead of current `\t`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `join()` instead of `@tsv`:

```
$ jq -r '.[]|[.id, .login, ([.groups[].name]|join("|"))]|@tsv' test.json
1e9b2215-9efd-67cc-9113-2b21c74f09d3    u0154   AGE
1e9b2215-9c2b-64f4-a0f1-47abdab7ae5f    u0155   ZZZ|NTE
```

Comment: thx. in addition I have modified it a bit because it failed on 'null' groups - I replaced .groups part in the filter to: ( if .groups == null then "null" else ([.groups[].name]|join("|")) end )